# Can I use accepts_nested_attributes_for hash in user_info_mapping or it isn't possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, external, sorcery

My user model has the following code:

```
has_one :settings,
  class_name: 'Setting', dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :settings, allow_destroy: true
```

And in the sorcery config I wrote:

```
config.vk.user_info_mapping = { login: "domain",
settings_attributes: { name: "full_name", about: "about" } }
```

Is that even possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is this sorcery you speak of?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I mean gem 'sorcery' for authentication.
https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery